# 16bit Texture with odd sized width is sheering

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, opengl-3

I am uploading a 35 x 100 16bpp texture with the following OpenGL command:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RG8, 35, 100, 0, GL_RG, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelData);
```

But the resulting texture is sheered by one pixel toward the left as y increases (both when drawn and when inspected in gpu memory):

```
o o x o o               o o o x o
o o x o o               o o o o x
o o x o o               x o o o o
o o x o o               o x o o o
o o x o o  becomes->    o o x o o
```

This type of sheering could occur if the width given differed from `pixelData` by one pixel, but the buffer and given dimensions are accurate.  Changing my texture to be 36 x 100 with no other changes fixes the issue as well.  This ONLY occurs for textures with an odd number as it's width.

My question is, is this a driver bug?  It was my understanding that non-POT textures were allowed on modern hardware, but this would suggest there's still some sort of unadvertised alignment requirement, perhaps specific to 16bpp textures; there's no mention of this behavior or requirement anywhere I could find at least.

Comment: What's the value of `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`?

Comment: @genpfault - Ah, it's 4.  I guess that explains it actually, it's padding to that on each pixel row at the end.  I didn't realize it could do that.

Comment: Make an answer (either of you two). Nobody has proposed a duplicate yet and it seems a non-obvious trap to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

Textures have an alignment they must meet at the end of each scanline (horizontal row), usually a default of 4 bytes.  If this alignment isn't met, the texture will need padding at these locations that you yourself must provide in the uploaded pixel data.  This isn't usually a concern until you mix non-pow2 texture sizes with less than 32bit per pixel texture data.

Using `glPixelStorei()` can adjust this requirement to an alignment of 2 or 1 as necessary, or you can simply ensure texture sizes align to a multiple of 4 when dealing with 16bit textures.